# Merging files with files which aren't in git

Tags: git, merge, branch

Some time ago I started to track my changes on source code via git.
Now the original author of the code released a new version. Now I want to merge the files via Git.

I'm new to Git, so I thought it would work, when I do the following:

```
git checkout -b new
```

Overwrite the old files with the new one

```
git commit -m "Replaced files with the new ones" -a
git checkout master
git merge new
```

This overwrites all my changes on master with the changes from the author.

But I want that the merge will create conflics, so I can just jump through the conflicts and decide to use my code or the code of the other author.

So maybe you know a solution.

EDIT it seems that it worked with this solution:

```
git checkout --orphan new
git rm -rf .
```

Upload the new files

```
git checkout --orphan merge
git rm -rf .
git merge master
git merge new
```

Comment: Use sdiff, meld, or similar.

Comment: Did you make a commit on your `new` branch after "overwriting the old files with the new ones" and before running `git checkout master`?

Comment: yep, I only forgot to add it to the post.

Comment: If you're telling us everything, it seems that Git was able to successfully carry out the merge without requiring your intervention (no merge conflicts). That should be good news :) Why do you insist on having to deal with merge conflicts?

Comment: because I want these merge conflicts. I think it's much easier to see these <<<<<<<<< HEAD things instead of diffing every file.

Comment: @mirko911 But, as I wrote in my earlier comment, there doesn't seem to be any conflict at all... If there are no conflicts, why would you want to create some out of thin air?

Comment: Because my edits got overwritten by the new files.